Is there a "mouseover" markup in wiki-markup in Jira
In jira-structure I have created some custom columns. One superconvenient feature is to be able to compare fields in the row and between child-parent-rows to validate that data is consistent with our workflow. But if there is several validation-errors I would like to present it as a single red E or some other short error icon and have some mouseover functionality on it. I would then like to show a popup with a longer custom message describing the error.
I can create the error and the custom message but its the mouseover-functionality that I cant get to work. Something like css-hover or css-title.
Q: Is there some way to get a mouseover-like-functionality?
